# Modifying an existing jar file through command prompt

Tags: java, jar, command, prompt

I'm trying to modify an existing class file in my JAR file through command prompt

I've used the following command:

jar uf

where class-file-name is the modified class file.

I expected the class to be overwritten with the contents of the modified class file, but the changes are not reflected.

Comment: Please provide the full command that was ran?

Comment: jar uf pass.jar Main.class ('pass' is the name of the jar file)

Comment: I placed the modified class file and the JAR file in the same location and entered the command prompt window from the same location

Comment: This(`jar uf pass.jar Main.class`) will add the class the root level in the jar. Is this the expected location?

Comment: oops. No, it's not. Looks like I've overlooked that detail. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

To add the class (Main.class) to a folder in a jar (pass.jar), use the following command:

`jar uf pass.jar com/tm/example/Main.class`

where `com/tm/example/` represents the directory for the class to be added to.

Comment: Hi J_D, another question: is it possible for the Main.class to be added from another directory to this JAR file?

Comment: Here is an example from the manual: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
      `jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ `.